# When to create a Wordpress Child Theme?

Tags: wordpress

When tweaking a wordpress theme's hard code with minimal tweaks, is it better to create a child theme or tweak with in live theme? Will your css changes disappear if the theme is updated?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've built a completely custom theme, child themes are **always** the recommended way of modifying an existing theme that you want to be able to apply updates to in the future.

If you modify a theme directly and it is updated, then your modifications may be lost. By using a child theme you will ensure that your modifications are preserved.

If you're not concerned with this, it's always possible to fork an existing theme, and make your own changes to the fork.

Answer (score 1):

You should not always create a child theme, but the fact still stands:

**NEVER EVER MODIFY THEMES OR PLUGINS YOU DID NOT CREATE, THE SAME APPLIES TO WORDPRESS CORE**

Before creating a child theme, ask yourself this question:

> What I'm about to do, does is benefit the theme or the site

What benefits the theme and should go into a child theme

- Custom templates
- Custom CSS and all visual elements. This is almost always theme related
- Customizations to templates
- Filters and actions which modifies theme specific functions and functionalities
- Customizations to parent theme functions

When should I rather create a custom plugin instead of a child theme

- Any type of functionality that enhances the functionality of the site. This includes favicons, custom post types, custom taxonomies, short codes, custom filters and actions to modify default functionality and all admin side customization ( this excludes theme related customizers ). This list wraps the important stuff and is not complete

  Remember, these are actions, filters and functionality that should still exist on the site when you switch themes

Comment: Great point about putting custom post type info, custom taxonomies, short codes, etc. in a plugin rather than a theme. Too often, developers throw all of this into a child theme and end up replacing the theme completely some time down the line.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to always create child theme and only override the files which you want to modify (by simply copying those into your child theme folder and then make your changes over there).
And yes any changes to main theme will be lost during updates so never make your changes directly to main theme.